# How to use 3 conditions in single formula?

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

How to use the following three conditions in Excel using single formula?

```
<=30 days
>30 days & <= 60 days
> 60 days
```

Answer (score 1):

You should nest two `IF` formulas:

```
=IF(A1<=30,val1,IF(A1<=60,val2,val3))
```

Where `A1` - address of tested value and `val1`, `val2`, `val3` are the results for the ranges 1,2,3.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (assuming the value is in cell A1):

```
=IF(OR(A1<=30, AND(A1>30,A1<=60), A1>60), TRUE, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to take 3 && conditions in a if function
like below
    if(a=="abhishek" && b==12345 && c=="my first teacher")
            {
                System.out.println("wel come have a nice day");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("match not found");
            }